# Why Zurb Foundation Top Bar not functioning?

Tags: html, zurb-foundation

I am learning Foundation 4.0 for a top bar design. My goal is just like the tutorial, to have slide effect of the menu item when the width goes narrower. I am following the document:
http://foundation.zurb.com/old-docs/f3/navigation.php#topbarCode

```
<div class="row">
<div class="twelve columns">
<nav class="top-bar">
  <ul>
    <!-- Title Area -->
    <li class="name">
      <h1>
        <a href="#">
          Top Bar Title
        </a>
      </h1>
    </li>
    <li class="toggle-topbar"><a href="#"></a></li>
  </ul>

  <section>
    <!-- Left Nav Section -->
    <ul class="left">
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li class="has-dropdown">
        <a class="active" href="#">Item 1</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><label>Section Name</label></li>
          <li class="has-dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="">Level 1, Has Dropdown</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
              <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
              <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="#">Level 2, Has Dropdown</a>
                <ul class="dropdown">
                  <li><label>Section</label></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Level 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Level 1</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><label>Section Name</label></li>
          <li><a href="#">Level 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Level 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Level 1</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">See all &rarr;</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="divider hide-for-small"></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Right Nav Section -->
    <ul class="right">
      <li class="divider show-for-medium-and-up"></li>
      <li class="has-dropdown">
        <a href="#">Item 2</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><label>Section Name</label></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="">Level 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Dropdown Option</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Dropdown Option</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><label>Section Name</label></li>
          <li><a href="#">Dropdown Option</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Dropdown Option</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Dropdown Option</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">See all &rarr;</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</nav>
</div>
</div>
```

I used this code absolutely the same as my environment. However the menu goes like this:

[image: 1]

It is not what I wish to have. Is anyone has the same problem as I have?

Comment: I have got it to work, please have a look at the code on [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/opaqum/3/edit), also look at [full screen preview](http://jsbin.com/opaqum/3/)

Comment: I got it work also. I include all the js files in to the page so the issue's gone. Your code is better and cleaner, Praveen. Thank you!

That's my puzzle: presentation.css is not in a package but it is broadly used in Foundation 4 Website.

Comment: According to a [comment](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/27#issuecomment-2508644) on github, **presentation.css** contains the specific styles for the marketing site and documentation - not part of the main Foundation package. You can get those files by checking out the whole repo.

Comment: If you have it fixed please post the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load all the js files Foundation 4 provides